# insert i variable from for loop in filename using java/ javafx

Tags: java, javafx

How am I able to insert the i from the for loop in the imageview below, not the i to replace 12 in the file name so that it can become;

```
ImageView Moon_img12 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/i.png")));
```

Code:

```
for(int i=0; i<=total_donnation; i++)
{
    ImageView Moon_img12 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/12.png")));

 }
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the variable after declaring and initializing it? Perhaps you want an array or a list?

Comment: Oh. I forgot. Was going to insert this image view in a grid.

Comment: @JonSkeet why does it matter?  It seems to me that Ossama has removed the irrelevant details from his question.  I wish more people would ask questions in this way.

Comment: @Ossama I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.  Are you saying you have a whole lot of files with names like `"/Images/tiles/0.png"`, `"/Images/tiles/1.png"`, `"/Images/tiles/2.png"` and so on?

Comment: So what goes wrong if you just write `"/Images/tiles/" + i + ".png"` in place of the hard-coded filename?

Comment: I tried this but did not write properly. Thanks it is good. How about Moon_img?

Comment: Oh, so you actually want to keep variables in scope, that reference your `ImageView` objects?  In that case, you'll definitely want either an array or a list.  You could write `ImageView[] moonImages = new ImageView[numberOfImages];` then refer to each one as `moonImages[i]`.

Comment: thanks, excuse me for being a noob, but how do i refer to the file path in the array above

Comment: I'm sorry, Ossama, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: how can i use this"/Images/tiles/" + i + ".png" in the array you mentioned above

Comment: Inside your loop, you want `moonImages[i] = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/" + i +".png")));`

Comment: @David: It matters because the variable name in the example suggests a correlation which would suggest using an array to store the image references - as you later suggested in your own comment. So it *was* relevant...

Comment: i am getting a null exception in the second line. ImageView[] moonImages = new ImageView[total_donnation];
        moonImages[i] = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/" + i +".png")));
        grid.add(moonImages[i], current_row, current_column);

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, I bow to your superior foresight.  I really thought that the missing bits were bits Ossama had chosen to omit, not bits he didn't know how to do.

Comment: @Ossama - create your array BEFORE the loop, and its entries INSIDE the loop.

Comment: I had chosen to omit to simplify!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

ImageView[] moon_images  = //init array

//loop

ImageView Moon_img = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/"+i+".png

moon_images[i]= Moon_img;

Comment: Thanks. But Moon_img should have the I as well instead of 12 as I have many pictures

Comment: Variable name cannot be dynamically decided...what is the intention of having it dynamic ??

Comment: Edited and to put image objects in a map with name which can be used when named access is required...hope this works

Comment: I have a bunch if images that I want to insert in grid depending on progress. I use the for loop to check progress and insert corresponding number if photos.

Comment: Then why not try adding image objects into a list inside the loop and use it wherever required ??

Comment: Never heard of image map. I M using javafx and want to insert the image views in a gridview

Comment: I need to insert each image individually in the grid at a certain location . grid.add(moonImages[i], current_row, current_column);

Comment: here is my fore loop to get an idea of what i want to implement. for(int i=1; i<=total_donnation; i++)
    {

        current_column = current_column++;
        if (current_column == max_columns )
        {
            current_row = current_row++;
            current_column = 0;
        }
        ImageView[] moonImages = new ImageView[i];
        moonImages[i] = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/" + i +".png")));
        grid.add(moonImages[i], current_row, current_column);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all, i have solved it now using your help.

```
   GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            int max_columns = 5;
            int current_row = 0;
            int current_column = 0;
            int total_donnation = 7;
            for(int i=1; i<=total_donnation; i++)
            {
                ImageView Moon_img = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Images/tiles/"+i+".png")));
                grid.add(Moon_img, current_column,current_row);       
                current_column = current_column+1;
                if (current_column == max_columns )
                {
                    current_row = current_row+1;
                    current_column = 0;
                }
            }
            return grid;
```